# how to programmatically enable Auto-start option for my app in Lenovo devices?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, autostart, background-service

I need to enable auto-start for Lenovo device if it is not enabled.
Settings -> Power Manager -> Background App Management -> enable my app.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: No, not yet. Stilling finding the solution. Please let me know if you have any solutions ?

Comment: Sure. But now user have to do it self.

Comment: using your way i am enabling my app in background list then  i clear my app from recent apps my service fully killed and onTaskRemoved method doesnot execute?can you please tell me if you know answer this issue?@Arihant Jain

Comment: Not yet, We have to perform this task manually.

Answer (score 0):

Android provide broadcast `BOOT_COMPLETED` to auto start apps. But some manufactures add additional permissions like you have mentioned for performance/battery improvement.Only user can white list your application in these scenario.

Comment: Can you please provide me the code ? BOOT_COMPLETED will restart the services when device is restart. I want to know how can i Auto-start screen using code similar as we can open in xiaomi devices ?

Comment: Auto-Start screen can be open only red-mi devices via programmatically. Otherwise user need to perform this task manually.